# Migrating svn 1.4 repo's to 1.6, populating node origins

Tags: svn

I just upgraded to SVN 1.6.1 from 1.4, and in the various docs, it is recommended to run svnadmin upgrade  and compile svn-populate-node-origins-index.c and run them on the repos to generate node-origins records that should speed up in svn-log processing.

svnadmin upgrade went fine and swift, h owever I have trouble compiling it (FC11). Any pointers before I go on a wild goose chase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compile svn-populate-node-origins-index:

- install subversion-devel RPM packages.
- configure source subversion start make and nick the cmdline
  (see below for what I found). Once you have it you can abort the compiling
  To do this I had to install sqlite-devel that is somehow not included in
  subversion-devel. (different configuration of the backend?)

  Not doing this will probably get you stranded on some off64_t problem.
  (probably the -DLARGEFILE64_SOURCE below)
- trial and error adding libraries based on header names in the source file.
- FC seems to suffix headers and libraries with 1, which I assume is the
  major version

The resulting commandline then became.

`gcc  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE  -g -O2 -pthread - I/usr/include/subversion-1/ -I/usr/include/apr-1 svn-populate-node-origins-index.c -lapr-1 -lsvn_repos-1`

Running this went fine, it lists the numbers of entries found, and indeed on the more branched and merged repo's it finds more.

After this, I also had to review some filesystem permissions in the
various repositories, for the newly generated directories and files. (apparantly g+s
wasn't everywhere to make it automatic)

Answer (score 0):

I never really had the need to compile svn-populate-node-origins-index.c but I usually simply run the svnadmin upgrade command.

Could you provide some reference for svn-populate-node-origins-index.c?
The [official release note](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html) provides the following instructions:

> Repository Upgrades
>
> The Subversion 1.6 server works with
>   1.5 and older repositories, and it will not upgrade such repositories to
>   1.6 unless specifically requested to via the svnadmin upgrade command. This
>   means that some of the new 1.6
>   features will not become available
>   simply by upgrading your server: you
>   will also have to upgrade your
>   repositories. (We decided not to
>   auto-upgrade repositories because we
>   didn't want 1.6 to silently make
>   repositories unusable by 1.5 — that
>   step should be a conscious decision on
>   the part of the repository admin.)

Comment: I wanted to experiment with mergetracking, so needed at least 1.5, while I had 1.4. I can't find the exact link anymore (but know it was on collab.net, and had similar remarks as http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-12/0238.shtml)

IOW it is used to speed up logs when you use mergetracking.